# KineticJS actual text height

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm having a problem getting the actual text height of a text object.

```
var btnText = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: xTracker,
        y: headerY,
        fill: '#a2b1c3',
        text: buttonText,
        width: buttonWidth,
        fontSize: 40,
        fontFamily: 'impact',
        align: 'center'
    });
```

All of the following methods return the same number, 40, which is not the actual height of the text.

```
btnText.getHeight();
btnText.getTextHeight();
btnText._getTextSize().height;
```

For debugging purposes, I added the following Rect to show the text region

```
var tmp = new Kinetic.Rect({            
            x: btnText.getPosition().x,
            y: btnText.getPosition().y,
            fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            width: btnText.getWidth(),
            height: btnText.getHeight()
        });
```

Here is the result:

[image]

You can see that the gray box (i.e. the text region) is larger than the actual text.  I need to actual text size within the region.

Comment: can you post your code to a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/peter_roca/LKNJp/52/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

```
var metrics = context.measureText(label);
```